# How can I configure IntelliSense in VSCode to offer suggestions for Dart class names when creating classes or constructors?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, intellisense

VSCode won't suggest autocompletions for class names when creating constructors or typing the class name for extending / implementing / mixins.

```dart
class SomeClass {
  SomeClass(); // No autocomplete when typing constructor.
}

class AnotherClass extends SomeClass {} // No autocomplete for `SomeClass`.

void main() {
  final someObject = SomeClass(); // Autocomplete suggestions do work.
}
```

I've looked through the VSCode settings and haven't found anything that seems related to this.

Comment: Have you installed the [flutter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter)?

Comment: I have the extension installed, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the setting for this.

In settings.json, in the dart section:

```json
  "[dart]": {
    "editor.suggest.showClasses": true
  },
```